# CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [date <-> java.util.Date]

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am using below Datastax versions with Java 8:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.2</version> 
    </dependency>
```

My table has a Date column as below:

```
cass_table (                                                    
    data_source_id int,                                                                                                                                                                   
    company_id text,                                                              
    create_date date)
```

When I trying to save the data into C* table as below:

```
final IndustryCompany four = new IndustryCompany(1,1236, ProdUtils.today());
 industryCompanyRepository.save(one);


public static Date today() {
        return java.sql.Date.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat(ProducerConstants.DATABASE_DATE_FORMAT).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    }
```

Getting error:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [date <-> java.sql.Date]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:57) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.7.2.jar:na]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass variable with `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate` type instead. See the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping) for mapping between Java type and CQL types.  You can use `LocalDate` from JDK 8, or from Joda time package if you'll use so-called [optional codec](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#jdk-8).

Another possibility is to [write](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/custom_codecs/) `date`<->`java.sql.Date` and register it for direct mapping.

Comment: thank you ... When I use version 4.0.0 instead of current version 3.7.2   to run https://github.com/lankydan/datastax-java-driver  ... there are lot of errors... is there any samples/examples to use  version 4.0.0 ???

Comment: 4.x is major rewrite of the Java driver, and it's not binary compatible.  There is a separate part of manual regarding porting: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.1/upgrade_guide/ And examples are in repository: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/4.x/examples

Comment: thank you , what do you mean by "not binary compatible" ??

Comment: That you can’t simply take your compiled code and use with new driver version, as there are API changes

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot @Alex Ott
As you suggested I did below

added another  jar

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Before calling save() method i called this

```
public void registerCodecs() {
    CodecRegistry registry = this.session.getCluster().getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry();
    registry.register(LocalDateCodec.instance);
}
```

Comment: you can look into my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45815737/2320144