# How can I resolve CodecNotFoundException for date <-> java.util.Date when using Cassandra Java driver 3.11?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

System.out.println("Enter date of birth (yyyy-MM-dd):");
String dateOfBirth = scanner.nextLine();

```
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date birthDate;
        try {
            birthDate = dateFormat.parse(dateOfBirth);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
        }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much details but it looks like this is a duplicate of [CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [date <-> java.util.Date]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111413/).

The CQL `date` type maps to the driver's `LocalDate` as listed in the [CQL-to-Java-type mapping](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping) table. You will need to create a codec to map the CQL `date` to a Java date type.

For details, see [Custom Codecs in Java driver 3.11](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/manual/custom_codecs/). Cheers!